# DataContext in ContentControl doesnt work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am working with WPF application using MaterialDesign for WPF.
I have created MainWindow which contains navigation drawer. 
Here is the XAML of MainWindow:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost>
    <materialDesign:DrawerHost IsLeftDrawerOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MenuToggleButton}">
        <materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
        <!--Drawer content-->
        </materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>

        <!-- Here is my Content-->
        <ContentControl Name="ContentControl"/>
    </materialDesign:DrawerHost>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

In the ViewModel of MainWindow I added OnMenuItemSelected method which will
set new content to ContentControl as below:

```
public void OnMenuItemSelected(object menuItem)
{
    var itemName = (DrawerMenuItem)menuItem;
    switch (itemName)
    {
        case DrawerMenuItem.Home:
            var window = new ProceduresWindow();
            _contentControl.Content = window.Content;
            break;
        //others
    }
}
```

In above example when I click Home button in drawer content of ContentControl should be replace with another Window in this example ProcedureWindow. 
New ProcedureWindow has DataContext set in XAML as below:

```
 <Window.DataContext>
        <windows:ProceduresViewModel></windows:ProceduresViewModel>
  </Window.DataContext>
```

Content is replacing correct but ViewModel is not working. Anyone know how can I solve that?

Comment: You could instantiate ProcedureViewModel directly without creating the window and setting that to Content as a start. If that does not help, you could explain what you mean about "ViewModel is not working". Error messages, experienced behavior, expected behavior and so on. That would help us helping you.

Comment: There is no error message - binding is not working. How do I do it directly?

Comment: Please, show me a databinding that is not working

Comment: I have changed Window to UserControl and it works

Comment: <TextBox Text="{Binding Typed, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/> is not woking for example and I have property Typed in VM

Comment: I would recommend using DataTemplates for mapping views and viewmodels when dealing with ContentControls. That way you do not have to instantiate the view, only the viewmodel. The framework can select the appropriate view defined by the datatemplate mappings. And yes, you cannot put a Window into any container. The window should be a root element of the visual tree.